# What does a query selector return in zombie.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zombie.js

I am learning Zombie.js with node.js using `sys.debug()` statements to track my progress. What is returned by calls like this `t = browser.body.querySelector(".navigation");` ? It is hard to tell what is going on without browser developer tools or something like php's `var_dump`. The [API](http://zombie.labnotes.org/API) doesn't really explain it.

How do I unpack this?

```
t = browser.body.querySelector(".navigation");
sys.debug(t); //returns "DEBUG: [ UL.navigation]" I don't know what this means.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.querySelector()` is defined as part of a [DOM API](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR), specifically the [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/), which Zombie.js is using [an implementation of](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

So, as it does in other browsers, [it should return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector):

> [...] the first element that is a descendent of the element on which it is invoked that matches the specified group of selectors.

In this case, based on the `UL.navigation` in the log, `t` is an `HTMLUListElement`. Or:

```
<ul class="navigation"></ul>
```

And, in cases where no matching `Element` can be found, it'll return `null`.